# Creating a seat map

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Hi would like some assistance please.

On sheet 1 I have prepared a list of passenger names with seats numbers in the following column each in individual cells eg 1A, 6B etc

EG column 1 passenger name - B SMITH,  column 2 seat No - 12A

On sheet 2 I have a seat map with rows 1A 1B 1C 1D etc through to row 19A B C D each seat number in a seperate cell.

What I would like to do is have the cell on sheet 2 reflect the number 1 if the seat is occupied and if the seat is empty then the cell on sheet 2 would be empty too.

So in the above example sheet 2 would have the number 1 in the cell on sheet 2 which represents 12A, all othwr cells would be empty.

Hope this makes sense.  Thanks in anticipation.  Debb

Answer (score 0):

Assuming seat numbers are in column A of sheet 2, you could put this formula in column B of sheet 2:

=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!B:B,0),"")

The MATCH formula is checking for seat number (in column A of sheet 2), against seat numbers in column B of sheet 1.  If it doesn't find it, the error #N/A will occur, so the IFERROR replaces those errors with blank.  Otherwise, you should get value of 1 if seat number is found.

Replace Sheet1 with the actual name of your worksheet containing the passenger names.

Comment: Sorry pressed enter in  error for this message

Comment: Thanks so much for this formula, it was very helpful and the closest I've come to finding a solution,  only problem is that the cell on the seat map that needs the number 1 in it is returning the line number from the passenger list.  Any suggestions?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry had my test data in row 1 so it was returning 1.  Forgot MATCH would return position.  This adds another layer, checking if the cell would be "" after error test for match; if it is then leave it as "", otherwise we've found a match so set value to 1:   =IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!B:B,0),"")="","",1)